# Looking to find a formula that can do this [My Excel can use filter and unique formulas]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For each year, exclude all data from columns `B` and `C` that are identical to columns `D` and `E` respectively AND ignore all data that are blank. Then write down all data remaining without blank lines in between.

|  | Datas |  | Criterias | to exclude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 13 | (Fx) |  |  |
| 2017 | 8 | (E) |  |  |
| 2017 | 12 | (E) |  |  |
| 2017 | 12s | (E) |  |  |
| 2017 | 46 | (E) |  |  |
| 2017 | 50 | (E) |  |  |
| 2017 | 8 | (Fu) |  |  |
| 2017 |  |  | 8 | (E) |
| 2017 |  |  | 12 | (E) |
| 2018 | 13 | (Fx) |  |  |
| 2018 | 8 | (E) |  |  |
| 2018 | 12 | (E) |  |  |
| 2018 | 12s | (E) |  |  |
| 2018 | 46 | (E) |  |  |
| 2018 | 50 | (E) |  |  |
| 2018 | 8 | (Fu) |  |  |
| 2018 | 13 | (Fu) |  |  |
| 2018 |  |  | 13 | (Fx) |
| 2018 |  |  | 46 | (E) |
| 2018 |  |  | 50 | (E) |
| 2018 |  |  | 8 | (Fu) |
| 2018 |  |  | 13 | (Fu) |
| 2019 | 13 | (Fx) |  |  |
| 2019 | 8 | (E) |  |  |
| 2019 | 12 | (E) |  |  |
| 2019 | 50 | (E) |  |  |
| 2019 | 8 | (Fu) |  |  |
| 2019 |  |  |  |  |
| 2019 |  |  |  |  |
| 2019 |  |  |  |  |
| 2019 |  |  | 8 | (E) |
| 2019 |  |  | 50 | (E) |
| 2019 |  |  | 8 | (Fu) |

here is the expected output:

| The | Expected | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | 13 | (Fx) |
| 2017 | 12s | (E) |
| 2017 | 46 | (E) |
| 2017 | 50 | (E) |
| 2017 | 8 | (Fu) |
| 2018 | 8 | (E) |
| 2018 | 12 | (E) |
| 2018 | 12s | (E) |
| 2019 | 13 | (Fx) |
| 2019 | 12 | (E) |

Anyone has an answer? thanks

Comment: Per your statement you want to exclude values from `D` and `E` column, NOT rows, but then value `8,12` from `D` and `(E)` from column `E`, should be excluded, but in the expected result you include rows from  `B` and `C` that have such values. Please clarify it in your question

Comment: @DavidLeal Not quite…  If you look year by year—in 2017, 8(E) and 12(E) are excluded *from year 2017* but not from other years.  The exclusion values in columns D and E are each associated with a year in column A, and are excluded only from that year but not other years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=FILTER(A2:C34,1-ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2:A34&"|"&B2:B34&"|"&C2:C34,A2:A34&"|"&D2:D34&"|"&E2:E34,0)))`

Comment: Very concise solution, just a comment it could be shorten more using `ISNA`. The final formula would be like this: `FILTER(A2:C34,ISNA(MATCH(A2:A34&"|"&B2:B34&"|"&C2:C34, A2:A34&"|"&D2:D34&"|"&E2:E34,0)))`

Comment: Thanks! this works out pretty good!  I have a follow up question and I am not sure if you can answer it https://stackoverflow.com/q/74020729/20095078

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this way:

```
=LET(lookup_array, 
 BYROW(FILTER(FILTER(A2:E34, (D2:D34<>"") * (E2:E34<>"")),{1,0,0,1,1}), 
 LAMBDA(row, CONCAT(row))),
 exclude,ISNA(XMATCH(A2:A34 & B2:B34 & C2:C34, lookup_array)), 
 FILTER(A2:C34, exclude * (B2:B34<>"") * (C2:C34<>"")))
```

and here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

We are going to use `XMATCH(lookup_value, lookup_array)` concatenating both input arguments to exclude concatenated rows that matches. For the `lookup_value` is trivial, just using ampersand operator (`&`): `A2:A34&B2:B34&C2:C34`, but for the second argument we need to build it.

```
FILTER(FILTER(A2:E34, (D2:D34<>"") * (E2:E34<>"")),{1,0,0,1,1})
```

just filter the exclusion criteria removing empty ones (inner `Filter`) and just selecting **Year**, **B** and **C** columns (outer `FILTER`).

**Note**: Alternatively `HSTACK` can be used instead of having a second filter:

```
FILTER(HSTACK(A2:A34, D2:E34), (D2:D34<>"") * (E2:E34<>""))
```

Here the intermediate result:

```
2017    8   (E)
2017    12  (E)
2018    13  (Fx)
2018    46  (E)
2018    50  (E)
2018    8   (Fu)
2018    13  (Fu)
2019    8   (E)
2019    50  (E)
2019    8   (Fu)
```

we use `BYROW` to concatenate all columns by row:

```
BYROW(FILTER(FILTER(A2:E34, (D2:D34<>"") * (E2:E34<>"")),{1,0,0,1,1}), 
 LAMBDA(row, CONCAT(row)))
```

Now we have all input arguments ready for our `XMATCH`. Because we want to exclude, we are interested on `#N/A` values only. The final `FILTER` will do the rest, remove empty `B` and `C` rows and and the `FALSE` values from `exclude` variable.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for your explanation. This is great. I just started using excel and I appreciate very much the detailed instructions. Thanks for your time. Can you answer this one as the follow up Q https://stackoverflow.com/q/74020729/20095078 ?