# Combine automatically all values from ranges of cells into A new format range of cells (automated) without VBA/Macros

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to combine automatically all values from ranges of cells into A new format range of cells using Excel formulas, and I wonder if it's possible. Thanks

Here is the input data:

| Year | Class | Type | New | Class | Type | Old |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 13 | (Fx) | $ 15 025,16 |  |  |  |
| 2018 | 8 | (E) | $ 4 185,07 |  |  |  |
| 2018 | 12 | (E) | $ 2 173,79 |  |  |  |
| 2018 | 12s | (E) | $ 75,66 |  |  |  |
| 2018 | 46 | (E) | $ 470,92 |  |  |  |
| 2018 | 50 | (E) | $ 1 869,14 |  |  |  |
| 2018 | 8 | (Fu) | $ 2 111,45 |  |  |  |
| 2018 | 13 | (Fu) | $ 28 942,45 |  |  |  |
| 2018 |  |  |  | 13 | (Fx) | $ 3 397,14 |
| 2018 |  |  |  | 46 | (E) | $ 19,98 |
| 2018 |  |  |  | 50 | (E) | $ 570,00 |
| 2018 |  |  |  | 8 | (Fu) | $ 3 324,33 |
| 2018 |  |  |  | 13 | (Fu) | $ 873,70 |
| 2019 | 13 | (Fx) | $ 517,86 |  |  |  |
| 2019 | 8 | (E) | $ 4 365,76 |  |  |  |
| 2019 | 12 | (E) | $ 1 014,93 |  |  |  |
| 2019 | 50 | (E) | $ 3 296,12 |  |  |  |
| 2019 | 8 | (Fu) | $ 2 016,51 |  |  |  |
| 2019 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2019 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2020 |  |  |  | 8 | (E) | $ 267,60 |
| 2020 |  |  |  | 50 | (E) | $ 998,92 |
| 2020 |  |  |  | 8 | (Fu) | $ 251,86 |
| 2020 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2020 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2020 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2021 | 13 | (Fx) | $ 1 997,30 |  |  |  |
| 2021 |  |  |  | 8 | (E) | $ 7 733,39 |
| 2021 |  |  |  | 50 | (E) | $ 2 766,23 |
| 2021 |  |  |  | 8 | (Fu) | $ 5 880,03 |
| 2021 |  |  |  | 13 | (Fx) | $ 15 693,38 |
| 2021 |  |  |  | 13 | (Fu) | $ 22 274,74 |
| 2021 |  |  |  | 46 | (E) | $ 399,98 |

and this is the expected output for **Formula 1** (see explanation below):

| Year | Class | Type | Old | New |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 13 | (Fx) | $ 3 397,14 | $ 15 025,16 |
| 2018 | 46 | (E) | $ 19,98 | $ 470,92 |
| 2018 | 50 | (E) | $ 570,00 | $ 1 869,14 |
| 2018 | 8 | (Fu) | $ 3 324,33 | $ 2 111,45 |
| 2018 | 13 | (Fu) | $ 873,70 | $ 28 942,45 |
| 2018 | 8 | (E) | $ 4 185,07 | $ - |
| 2018 | 12 | (E) | $ 2 173,79 | $ - |
| 2018 | 12s | (E) | $ 75,66 | $ - |
| 2019 | 13 | (Fx) | $ - | $ 517,86 |
| 2019 | 8 | (E) | $ - | $ 4 365,76 |
| 2019 | 12 | (E) | $ - | $ 1 014,93 |
| 2019 | 50 | (E) | $ - | $ 3 296,12 |
| 2019 | 8 | (Fu) | $ - | $ 2 016,51 |
| 2020 | 8 | (E) | $ 267,60 | $ - |
| 2020 | 50 | (E) | $ 998,92 | $ - |
| 2020 | 8 | (Fu) | $ 251,86 | $ - |
| 2021 | 8 | (E) | $ 7 733,39 | $ - |
| 2021 | 50 | (E) | $ 2 766,23 | $ - |
| 2021 | 8 | (Fu) | $ 5 880,03 | $ - |
| 2021 | 13 | (Fx) | $ 15 693,38 | $ 1 997,30 |
| 2021 | 13 | (Fu) | $ 22 274,74 | $ - |
| 2021 | 46 | (E) | $ 399,98 | $ - |

I have uploaded the file in google sheet for convenience:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SE2B5m-sz-L55Gc5CePbBDMeggDj2cLMZlXHnYT282U/edit?usp=sharing

However I am looking for a solution in Excel (office 2021)

**Formula 1**

What I am looking for is to create a new range of cells (`L` to `M`) from the range of cells on the left side (col `A` to `G`).

- For each year:

  - if class (col `B`) and type (`C`) match respectively class (col `E`) and type (col `F`), write the value in text format of Col `B` in `I` and value of Col `C` in `J`, and get the value of col `D` in col `M` and the value of col `G` in col `L`.
  - if class (col `B`) and type (`C`) are not found respectively in class (col `E`) and type (col `F`) and are not `0` (i.e. is not blank row), write the value in text format of Col `B` in I and value of Col `C` in `J`, and get the value of col D in col M and put 0 as value in col `L`.
  - if class (col `E`) and type (`F`) are not found respectively in class (col `B`) and type (col `C`) and are not `0` (i.e. is not blank row), write the value in text format of Col `E` in `I` and value of Col `F` in `J`, and get the value of col `G` in col `L` and put `0` as value in col `M`.

**Formula 2**

What I am looking for is to create a new range of cells (`L` to `M`) from the range of cells on the left side (col `A` to `G`).

Equivalent to Google sheets Flatten formula, but with 2 columns in consideration rather than one (where the same row of the 2 columns is seen as "1 value" - like Flatten a pairing values).

- For each year:

  - Obtain the unique values of 2 arrays combined (array 1= col `B` and `C`, array 2= col `E` and `F`). By unique, it means Col `B` must match with Col `E` while for the same row, col `C` matches col `F`.

**Note**: The output will be the first 4 columns of the expected output of **Formula 1**.

Comment: Please be more descriptive in what you want to get (and why).

Comment: Done, i hope its better now.

Comment: Row 34 and up are messed up. Also, I've seen a previous question, kind of similar. What experience have you gained from there and what have you tried yourself getting the data how you want it?

Comment: @l4cky your input data Google Spreadsheet, has errors, the formulation in the that file, doesn't match with the statement in your question. Review your question, some columns and/or logic doesn't seem to match with the sample file and also some columns. Please review it. I have a very close solution, but I am not sure if the mismatches are from my end or from your data or specification. Thanks

Comment: sorry P.b  David Leal
You were right. i made a mistake in the tables and excel sheet. I correct it back, thanks for pointing it out! my bad.

Comment: @l4cky still the information is not correct. Per my understanding, the dollar amount on column `E` starting form row `34` should be on column `G`. All that information is permuted. In your question you state: "write the value in text format of Col B in I", but column `I` is a year, not the place we put the value of column `B`. Other people may have a similar question in  the future and found your question, but it is still with errors, so it will be difficult to follow.

Comment: you are 100% correct, sorry for the delay reading this

Answer (score 1):

Even though your question lacks your tries of getting in the direction or could easily be logged as separate questions by itself I managed to get the data using Office 365 (note that your expected result in your spreadsheet do not match the one shared as a screenshot).

I managed to sort the unique year / class / type rows and lookup the associated values for old and new:

```
=LET(
data,A6:G39,
   header1,INDEX(data,1,SEQUENCE(1,3)),
   header2,HSTACK(INDEX(data,1,7),INDEX(data,1,4)),
   d,DROP(data,1),
       y,INDEX(d,,1),
                nc,INDEX(d,,2),
                nt,INDEX(d,,3),
                nv,INDEX(d,,4),
                oc,INDEX(d,,5),
                ot,INDEX(d,,6),
                ov,INDEX(d,,7),
                ac,VSTACK(HSTACK(y,oc,ot),HSTACK(y,nc,nt)),
        uc,SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(ac,INDEX(ac,,2)<>""))),
formula1,VSTACK(header1,uc),
        br,BYROW(uc,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("",0,x))),
           ol,XLOOKUP(br,y&oc&ot,ov,0,0),
           nl,XLOOKUP(br,y&nc&nt,nv,0,0),
formula2,VSTACK(HSTACK(header1,header2),HSTACK(uc,ol,nl)),
formula2)
```

The final argument in the LET-function is set to `formula2` for getting the complete view including headers & values for what you described Formula 2 in your question.

Changing the final argument to `formula1` would result in the requested result for what you described Formula 1 in your question.

I made it dynamical, so if you change the range for argument `data` the calculation will adopt to that range.

I first stacked the *year* `y`, *class* values for the new values `nc` and the *type* values for the new values `nt` and the *year* `y`, *class* values for the old values `oc` and the *type* values for the old values `ot`.
and sorted it, showed unique values only and filtered out rows showing blank data in the *class* column.

Then I performed a TEXTJOIN by row to this array `br` to be used to lookup the
associated old values `ol` and for the new values `nl`.

Than I stacked the headers, unique sorted filtered year/class/type and it's lookup values as a whole.

[image]

I recommend you to split the parts into separate questions if you would want to calculate this in a different Excel version (or that would've been my recommendation anyway).

EDIT:
I also have an alternative version leaving out the headers, but avoiding `DROP`, `VSTACK` and `HSTACK`, all being function not available to Excel 2021 as far as I could find.

This formula should work in Excel 2021:

```
=LET(
data,A6:G39,
r,ROWS(data)-1,
c,COLUMNS(data)+1,
sr,SEQUENCE(r*2,),
sm,MOD((sr-1),r)+2,
dn,INDEX(data,sm,SEQUENCE(1,4)),
   _dn1,INDEX(dn,,1),
   _dn2,INDEX(dn,,2),
   _dn3,INDEX(dn,,3),
   _dn4,INDEX(dn,,4),
do,INDEX(data,sm,{1,5,6,7}),
   _do1,INDEX(do,,1),
   _do2,INDEX(do,,2),
   _do3,INDEX(do,,3),
   _do4,INDEX(do,,4),
da,IF(sr<=r,do,dn),
_fa,SORT(FILTER(da,ISTEXT(INDEX(da,,3)))),
_ufa,UNIQUE(INDEX(_fa,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_fa)),SEQUENCE(1,3))),
   _fa1,INDEX(_ufa,,1),
   _fa2,INDEX(_ufa,,2),
   _fa3,INDEX(_ufa,,3),
_lo,XLOOKUP(_fa1&_fa2&_fa3,_do1&_do2&_do3,_do4,0,0),
_ln,XLOOKUP(_fa1&_fa2&_fa3,_dn1&_dn2&_dn3,_dn4,0,0),

CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5},_fa1,_fa2,_fa3,_lo,_ln))
```

(the `_ufa`-part is equal to the data for Formula 2, as you described in your question)

And including the headers

```
=LET(data,A6:G39,r,ROWS(data)-1,c,COLUMNS(data)+1,sr,SEQUENCE(r*2,),sm,MOD((sr-1),r)+2,dn,INDEX(data,sm,SEQUENCE(1,4)),_dn1,INDEX(dn,,1),_dn2,INDEX(dn,,2),_dn3,INDEX(dn,,3),_dn4,INDEX(dn,,4),do,INDEX(data,sm,{1,5,6,7}),_do1,INDEX(do,,1),_do2,INDEX(do,,2),_do3,INDEX(do,,3),_do4,INDEX(do,,4),da,IF(sr<=r,do,dn),_fa,SORT(FILTER(da,ISTEXT(INDEX(da,,3)))),_ufa,UNIQUE(INDEX(_fa,SEQUENCE(ROWS(_fa)),SEQUENCE(1,3))),_fa1,INDEX(_ufa,,1),_fa2,INDEX(_ufa,,2),_fa3,INDEX(_ufa,,3),_lo,XLOOKUP(_fa1&_fa2&_fa3,_do1&_do2&_do3,_do4,0,0),_ln,XLOOKUP(_fa1&_fa2&_fa3,_dn1&_dn2&_dn3,_dn4,0,0),result_data,CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5},_fa1,_fa2,_fa3,_lo,_ln),
header,INDEX(data,1,{1,2,3,7,4}),
IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(result_data)+1)<=1,header,INDEX(result_data,SEQUENCE(ROWS(result_data)+1,,0),SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(header)))))
```

Comment: yeah I don't have DROP, VSTACK and HSTACK in my excel sadly.

I did try the other function for excel 2021 as you posted
=LET(data,A6:G39,
r,ROWS(data)-1,
etc..
But it gives me an error and this result:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SE2B5m-sz-L55Gc5CePbBDMeggDj2cLMZlXHnYT282U/edit#gid=1184671299

(JPG)

Comment: Does your Excel use `;`-separator? What is the formula you used? It works for me. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzhiH.jpg

Comment: yeah it uses the ; seperator, so i copied your formula, and replace All , with ;

I posted it in the same google sheet because the reply here has a max number of character https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SE2B5m-sz-L55Gc5CePbBDMeggDj2cLMZlXHnYT282U/edit#gid=1184671299

Comment: You forgot to replace them within the CHOOSE-part `{1;2;3;4;5}`

Comment: The `{}` brackets contain an array where the separator shows the direction of the array. In English `,` is for left to right, while `;` is from top to bottom. In your language it's `;` and `\` respectively.

Comment: for some reasons, choose only works with , in the {} but ; is used in formulas. I mean when I used ; it only shows one columns with Errors

Comment: I install a new excel in english in my other computer and the same problem happens, with your delimeters
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SE2B5m-sz-L55Gc5CePbBDMeggDj2cLMZlXHnYT282U/edit#gid=1471922443

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=C2332C47B39E641C!13811&ithint=file%2cxlsx&authkey=!APpM5TLUFAgldmE

Comment: I think you would be able to save a copy. If you open the copy it should show the formulae correctly (except errors for the VSTACK ones, probably)

Comment: I also made a correction to the non-VSTACK versions since there was an error in getting the unique values only

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution. Your input data and rules seem to have some inconsistences. I check my result for **formula 1** is the same as @P.b, so it seem we have the same understanding, but your question and data need to be reviewed.

Here is the **formula 1** in `O4`:

```
=LET(setY, FILTER(A4:C36, (B4:B36<>"") * (C4:C36<>"")), 
  amountY, FILTER(D4:D36, D4:D36<>""), 
  setX, FILTER(HSTACK(A4:A36, E4:F36), (E4:E36<>"") * (F4:F36<>"")), 
  amountX, FILTER(G4:G36, G4:G36<>""), 
  lkupY, BYROW(setY, LAMBDA(rowY, CONCAT(rowY))), 
  lkupX, BYROW(setX, LAMBDA(rowX, CONCAT(rowX))), 
  notMatchXInY, ISNA(XMATCH(lkupX, lkupY)), 
  SORT(IFERROR(VSTACK(HSTACK(setY, XLOOKUP(lkupY,lkupX, amountX), amountY), 
    FILTER(HSTACK(setX, amountX, XLOOKUP(lkupX,lkupY, amountY)),
      notMatchXInY)),""),1))
```

and here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

**Note:** In light yellow (columns `E:G`) data I think they were miss placed in the input data from the question (it was corrected in the question after)

**Formula 2** is just a partial result from the data in `formula 1`:

```
=LET(setY, FILTER(A4:C36, (B4:B36<>"") * (C4:C36<>"")),  
  setX, FILTER(HSTACK(A4:A36, E4:F36), (E4:E36<>"") * (F4:F36<>"")),
  lkupY, BYROW(setY, LAMBDA(rowY, CONCAT(rowY))), 
  lkupX, BYROW(setX, LAMBDA(rowX, CONCAT(rowX))), 
  notMatchXInY, ISNA(XMATCH(lkupX, lkupY)), 
  VSTACK(setY, FILTER(setX, notMatchXInY))
)
```

or filtering by the three first columns from **formula 1** result, i.e.:

```
LET(formula2, FILTER(formula1, {1,1,1,0,0}), formula2)
```

where `formula1` represents the output of **formula 1**.

The output will just the first three columns from the result of **formula 1** (but without sorting, but it can be added, if needed)

### Explanation

I use the following suffixes to identify each set and related calculations:

- `X` for Old Data
- `Y` for New Data

We first filter by non empty rows of both sets (New and Old data). `SetY`, `SetX` represent such sets (not considering the amount part, just **Year**, **Class**  and **Type**):

```
setY, FILTER(A4:C36, (B4:B36<>"") * (C4:C36<>""))
setX, FILTER(HSTACK(A4:A36, E4:F36), (E4:E36<>"") * (F4:F36<>""))
```

Next we define the lookup variables, via concatenation of the search criteria:

```
lkupY, BYROW(setY, LAMBDA(rowY, CONCAT(rowY)))
lkupX, BYROW(setX, LAMBDA(rowX, CONCAT(rowX)))
```

The corresponding amount for each set:

```
amountY, FILTER(D4:D36, D4:D36<>"")
amountX, FILTER(G4:G36, G4:G36<>"")
```

Because the resulting output will be the unique values (**Year**, **Class** and **Type**) from both sets, we need to find the elements in `X` not in `Y` and for that we use this variable:

```
notMatchXInY, ISNA(XMATCH(lkupX, lkupY))
```

The rest is just to build the final result using `VSTACK`, `HSTACK` to build the result in the form we want.

We use `XLOOP` function to apply the following business rules: For elements in `setY` found in `setX`, we use `amountX` and `amountY` respectively. All the `#N/A` values (not found cases) are replaced at the end with an empty string (`""`). So this rule can be implemented as follow:

```
HSTACK(setY, XLOOKUP(lkupY,lkupX, amountX), amountY)
```

For the second set (Old Set). Elements from `SetX` not in `SetY` we obtain the amount as follow:

```
FILTER(HSTACK(setX, amountX, XLOOKUP(lkupX,lkupY, amountY)), notMatchXInY)
```

We use `XLOOKUP` in a similar way for previous `setY` and combine it with `HSTACK`. The only difference is to exclude `setX` elements already present in `setY` and for that we use a `FILTER`.

Comment: DROP, VSTACK and HSTACK in my excel sadly, Maybe that is why it gives me a blank result? sorry :(

Comment: @l4cky maybe you are referring to @P.b answer. In my approach I am not using `DROP`.

Comment: oh yeah sorry, i mean hstack  and vstack, yeah no drop in your formula

Comment: are you able to invoke both functions not on this problem, but just a simple invocation just to check you have access to those functions. For example: [HSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2), it has some note about availability in some versions. Please make sure that it not the problem. The only alternative that comes to my mind is to use CHOOSE function, in case you cannot use HSTACK, VSTACK, but it will make the formula larger

Comment: yeah in my excel 2021, when i use = vstack or hstack nothing happens. Choose functions works, however.

From what I read, it's only available through offisde insiders which requires a subscription to o365 and that is not included in excel 2021

Comment: [Here](https://exceljet.net/formula/combine-ranges-with-choose) is a comment that `CHOOSE` is an alternative for `HSTACK`

Comment: For the first `HSTACK` in my solution you can avoid it with  a second `FILTER(FILTER{1,,,0,1}`), for the other ones, probably returning the partial result in Excel, and then using such results as help range to build the final result you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248740/discussion-between-david-leal-and-l4cky).